# function to check if SQLite is using journal_mode=WAL or journal_mode=DELETE

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, journaling

I was looking for function which would help me to see which journaling mode is enabled..
I looked here too   [*list of function*](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html) 

 There was function to check database status [sqlite3_db_status(....)](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_status.html) but status parameter didn't have option for check journaling mode 
 
Is there a function or any way to find if sqlite db is using WAL-mode or normal journaling mode ..!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To query the journal mode of a connection, execute [PRAGMA journal_mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) and read the result.

Comment: If I have to read from a C++ program , how to read output of pragma as they may run on "sqlite3_prepare()" OR on step(). 
How should be my call like ??
Thank you for all those answers..>!!

Comment: You would read it like a `SELECT` query, i.e., `sqlite3_step` returns `SQLITE_ROW`, and you call `sqlite3_column_`*.