# How to use sqlite wal mode in windows mobile develop?

Tags: c#, sqlite, mobile

I am porgramming a c# program with sqlite database for windows mobile 6.5 devices. Here is how I create a database:

```
SQLiteConnection cn = new SQLiteConnection("Data source =" + dbPath + ";PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;");
```

My question is how can I know whether the SQLite database is working in WAL mode?

Comment: Literally the first two results from google: [Pragma statements supported by SQLite](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html) and [function to check if SQLite is using journal_mode=WAL or journal_mode=DELETE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901814/function-to-check-if-sqlite-is-using-journal-mode-wal-or-journal-mode-delete)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by knowing whether the SQLite database is working in WAL mode? Can't you simply read the value of the journal mode pragma?

I think that would work, assuming your connection is opened and valid (though I did not test it).

```
string sql = "PRAGMA journal_mode";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
var journalMode = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

journalMode should be set to "WAL", or maybe a corresponding number.

Good luck!
Antoine